# Socket.IO Getting 404 Errors on Some URLs, but not others

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to use Socket.IO in my web application and it has worked great so far. However, I have been trying to fix one specific issue for a long time and have not been able to find anyone else having the same issue. Socket.IO works great on URLs where it is just site.com/example, however, when I stack paths on the domain, I get a 404 in socket.IO. For example, site.com/user/example displays a 404 for socket.IO. In the log, it tries to access socket.IO at site.com/user/socket.io/... when it needs to access it at site.com/socket.io. It seems to only replace the url after the last / so site.com/ex/a would make it try to get socket.io at site.come/ex/socket.io.(I am using ExpressJS, I didn't know if that was relevant.)

I have tried to set the path and resource for socket.io to use in the client script. Also, I included the path when binding the socket.io instance to the http server.

Here is my server side code.

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {path: '/socket.io'});
```

Here is my client side code.

```
var socket = io.connect('https://example.net', {
    path: '/socket.io',
    resource: '/socket.io',
    transports: ['websocket'],
    upgrade: false
})
```

Thanks so much for all help!
(I am sorry for any incorrect formatting of this question, this is my fist time asking on StackOverflow!)

Comment: Are you errors when making a socket.io connection?  Or are the errors on the socket.io client `<script>` tag?  If the `<script>` tag, please show what script tag you are using because it has to use your path too.

Comment: FYI, I don't know what you're expecting the `resource` option does for `io.connect()` as I don't see that in [the socket.io docs](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#new-Manager-url-options).

Comment: @jfriend00 I have a .js script included in my header file, which I include in all of my other files. So, header.ejs is included by ```<%- include header %>``` . I just saw the resource option on a website and was desperate enough to try it out. Here is the Chrome console of the errors. https://ibb.co/cg0wXRj As you can see, those errors come up on https://example.net/user/fludo, but they don't on a URL such as https://example.net/dashboard.

Comment: Please show me the actual `<script>` tag that includes socket.io that's inside your header template.  I'm guessing it needs a leading `/` on the path.  Without that, it only works in top level URLs that don't have a path.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks so much! I CANNOT believe I didn't think about that.
changed from
```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```
to
```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: @jfriend00 Could you put that comment in an answer? I need to mark it as the solution and I do not think I can mark a comment as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need a leading slash on the socket.io script tag.

The big clue is when you said your `socket.io` script loads when the page URL is https://example.net/dashboard, but doesn't load when it's https://example.net/user/fludo.  And, the screen shot shows it trying to load the script from `https://example.net/user/fludo/socket.io/socket.io.js` which is, indeed, the wrong path.

The problem is that your `<script>` tag is using a page relative link with no leading `/` on the URL.  That means the browser will combine the path of the page URL with the filename in your `<script>` tag.  But, you don't want to use the path of the page.  You want to load it from the same place every time.  So, to do that, you change from this:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```